# GUID/GPT Partition scheme: OS X + Windows

Tags: windows-7, macos, hard-drive, partitioning, gpt

I always used Linux (Ubuntu) in a dual boot configuration with Windows (using Grub). Having Windows on your computer is always handy.

I bought a MacBook Pro 8.1 last week. OS X is amazing. I followed a video tutorial on how to setup a triple boot (OS X, Linux, Windows). Everything worked great after installing Windows next to OS X; for this I installed rEFIt and did some partitioning. When my MacBook Pro arrived, the partition scheme was GUID (also called GPT) *and I installed Windows 7 successfully.

Unfortunately I then screwed it up and needed to reinstall everything. I started with OS X, which works fine right now. During the installation of OS X I already partitioned my HDD in three partitions:

- `100 GB`: OSX
- `060 GB`: Windows
- `160 GB`: Stuff

Before I could install OS X, the setup said I had to use GUID (it was by default something else), which is the same partitioning scheme as in the beginning.

When I try to install Windows 7 for the second time (after I screwed it up), it says that I can't use a GPT Partitioning Scheme.

Why not? Why did it work the first time? Is there a way to solve this problem without having to format my HDD? If not, how do I have to prepare my HDD to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made it work. There are two special tricks you have to do.

1. First install OSX using the full HD, instead of partitioning in the setup. And partition when the setup is done.
2. Put your data/stuff partition in between OSX and Windows.

The blog that helped me out was this one: http://tripoverit.blogspot.com/2008/01/imac-dual-boot-mac-os-x-and-win-xp-with.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the Boot Camp Assistant utility that comes with OS X to set your partitions up for a Windows installation.

Comment: I've found it. Spotlight found it.

Comment: So, this means I have to reinstall everything once again? *sight*

Comment: Will I be able to create a Stuff partition as well, where I always put all my projects, videos, documents, photos?

Comment: I don't know how it will work with your existing partitions. I'd run it and see -- it will warn you before it actually wipes anything.